# Remove argument from $@ if it is an option

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I have a script where I need to loop through the arguments passed, and if an argument starts with `-` I need to put it in a string `opts` and remove it from `$@`. This is what I have so far

```
opts=""
for arg in "$@"
do
    if [[ "$arg" == -* ]]; then
        opts="${opts} ${arg}"
        # remove arg from $@ ??
    fi
done

echo $@
echo $args
```

How can I remove `arg` from the array of the arguments passed `$@`?

Comment: I have to remove it (also, it's cleaner to remove it from the already existing array than to create a new one).

Comment: Don't reinvent `getopts`. See related answers tagged with [tag:getopts].

Comment: Do you know what options you are expecting and whether any of these expects option-arguments? If so, you could just use `getopts` to parse the command line arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the options starting with `-` never take arguments, simply this will do, using an `opts` *array*:

```
for a; do
   shift
   case $a in
   -*) opts+=("$a");;
   *) set -- "$@" "$a";;
   esac
done
```

(change `opts+=("$a")` to `opts="$opts$a "` if you want `opts` to be a string, which will make the snippet work with any standard shell).

Comment: use the `getopts` builtin, then.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, ksh, zsh one expansion will clear all arguments that start with `-`:

```
echo "${@##-*}"
```

Note that that doesn't **remove** the arguments, just make them null.

However, getting the list of arguments that doesn't start with `-` while being able to deal with spaces and newlines gets quite more difficult.

A simple loop is preferable:

```
unset args opts;
for a; do
    if [[ $a == [-]* ]]; then
        opts+=("$a");
    else 
        args+=("$a");
    fi;
done;

printf '<%s> ' "${args[@]}"; echo;
printf '<%s> ' "${opts[@]}"; echo;
```

Comment: "$@"` with the arguments starting with `-` removed would be `"${@:#-*}"` in `zsh`.